# My indivually addressable LED strip is acting weirdly and I have no idea why

Tags: led

EDIT: I had a typo in the code. I updated the code below to reflect what is shown in the video.

[Video of the problem](https://imgur.com/gallery/BE3DTWU?s=sms)

I'm controlling my LEDs via the Neo_pixel Library for Arduino. My strip (SK6812, RGBW) takes 5V. I wrote very simple instructions for the strip: flash the whole strip one color, rest for 200ms, then flash the whole strip a second color, then rest another 200ms. This should be repeated indefinitely but when either chosen color is red (rgbw[255, 0, 0, 0]) or green (rgbw[0, 255, 0, 0]) the strip will function up as expected for a second or two then remains a solid red or green (depending on which color was chosen). This problem only seems to occur with red or green; blue and white appear to not be an issue. If someone has an idea I should try, please let me know!

The following code is what was executed in the video above: 
[Neo_Pixel Class Reference](https://adafruit.github.io/Adafruit_NeoPixel/html/class_adafruit___neo_pixel.html#a19fc274330c0e65907929ee03b93b1c3)

```
strip.fill(strip.color(255, 0, 0, 0), 0); //fills entire LED strip the color red
strip.show(); //Updates LED strip to reflect changes  
delay(200);   //200ms delay 
strip.fill(strip.color(0, 0, 0, 255), 0); //fills entire LED strip the color white
strip.show();
delay(200);
```

Comment: There's an error in your code, you're specifying the same color both times.  

Also, if you're commanding full-on white, I suspect you may be overloading your power supply and causing it to do whatever it does when you overload the power supply.

Comment: That code just shows red over and over.  How would you ever know if that has stopped?  Please post a complete code.

Comment: that is not the code that is running in the video ... either delete the video or delete the sketch

Comment: try `strip.color(32, 0, 0, 0)`, `strip.color(0, 32, 0, 0)`, etc. If that works you need a bigger PSU.

Comment: @Delta_G  Ah that's a typo! I copied the instructions to turn the LED strip red and forgot to change the RGBW value to white. The code now reflects what is shown in the video.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I thought this might be a problem but I wasn't sure how to tell. I figured if I overloaded the strip, it would go blank instead of remaining a color. I should also mention that the problem does not occur if I light up only half the pixels.

Comment: @dandavis I'm still learning the ropes of arduino, is a PSU just power supply?

Comment: yup. wall wort. usb charger. psu. dc supply. they have a lot of synonyms...

Comment: @dandavis I decreased the RGB values as you suggested and the strip works as expected, guess I gotta get more power! Thanks!